# Configure tensorboard to start with no smoothing -- for certain plots

Tags: tensorboard

Can I configure tensorboard to start with no smoothing? The smoothing can hide overfitting. If there was a command line option, or if tensorboard looked in a location like `~/.tensorboard/config.ini` that would be great.

As an example
[image: no smoothing eval loss]

But with the default smoothing it looks like

[image: default smoothing eval loss]

you've got to look at the second one closely to see your overfitting

or what would be even better, is to configure this per plot. Maybe even when making the `SummaryWriter` in the code.